# installing ruby-debug-ide on an offline machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, offline, ruby-debug

I'm trying to install ruby-debug-ide-0.4.15.gem on an Ubuntu 10.04 machine which is not connected to the Internet, and I get the following errors:

ERROR: Error installing ruby-debug-ide-0.4.15.gem:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/bin/ruby1.8 mkrf_conf.rb
ERROR: http://rubygems.org/ does not sappear to be a repository

Installing the same gem on a similar machine which is connected to the Internet, work fine.
What can be the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Because authors of ruby-debug-ide gem are an using extension mechanism not to build some library that was written in C, but *to install another gem* depending on your Ruby version. This is form ruby-debug-ide's `ext/mkrf_conf.rb` file:

```
inst = Gem::DependencyInstaller.new
begin
  if RUBY_VERSION < "1.9"
    inst.install "ruby-debug-base", '>=0.10.4'
  else
    inst.install "ruby-debug-base19", '>=0.11.24'
  end
  rescue
    exit(1)
end
```

It tries to download and install ruby-debug-base gem.